# Cordova Webview -webkit-backface-visibility not working

Tags: android, cordova, webview, css-transforms

I create a simple Android application using the latest version of Cordova and replace content of www folder by sample code of a memory game written by Igor Minar on Github (https://github.com/IgorMinar/Memory-Game). The problem is the cover image (front side) does not display. The cards always display the content image (back side) for both sides.
Then I create a new Android application without Cordova but use a simple android.webkit.WebView and everything work as expected with similar www content.
I think this is an issue of Cordova Webview. I want to use Cordova because it's a good SDK so I want to ask if someone can give me a solution for this webview issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show me what you have done.

Comment: 1. I run cordova cli command to create the android project
2. I updated the index.html file with the code from app\index.html of example to enable the AngularJS and display the cards.
3. I copied necessary css, js, lib files from the example and put into the corresponding directories in assets\www folder.
4. When running application, there was only -webkit-backface-visibility not working; transform effect is working fine.

Comment: I tested on iOS and this css attribute is working fine. So I believe the issue is occurred on the Cordova for Android only. I tested with several Android versions: from 3.0 to 4.3 with both emulators and real devices but all of them get this issue.

Comment: Any update? I've got the same issue with android webview (not cordova in particular) android version <= 4.3, in 4.4+ (because it's a chromeview it works like a charm)

Answer (score 1):

After a long experimentation using this website: http://thewebrocks.com/demos/3D-css-tester/
([source code on github](https://github.com/codepo8/3D-css-tester))
and based on the code of @nguyen-canh-linh, which he manages to get working  even in Android < 4.4 webview ([see on his repository](https://github.com/IgorMinar/Memory-Game))

I found that you CAN NOT have two css properties animated in the same class - but I was aware of that fact (a bug I read about on the Internet) - I did not realize that the trick needed to avoid flickering in recent webkit version ie: `* { transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }` was indeed seen as an animation and triggers the bug

Note: also be careful with: `backface-visibility: hidden;` do not apply it to every element (*), it could be buggy as well.